# Unreal Blueprint node DrawDebugString doesn't work

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I have a `DrawDebugString` node setup in the tick of my character like this:

[image: DrawDebugString Node Setup]

However, nothing was showing in the game. I've checked that it gets called (every frame), the location is correct and the string is non-empty. I'm using Unreal Engine version `5.0.0-19505902+++UE5+Release-5.0`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this [Unreal Forum Post](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/cant-see-draw-debug-string-help/409072/11). The reason it wasn't working was that we weren't using a HUDClass in our project. To fix this I had to change the `HUD Class` setting in the `Class Defaults` of our game mode from `None` to `HUD`:

[image: HUD Class setting in GameMode]

This seems to be a problem/solution for both UE4 or UE5.